# Filling an image with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a coffee pot that can fill and drain with css/js. My idea was to create a coffee pot image, and fill the middle with css that I can animate based on how much I want the coffee pot to be filled. I'm not sure how to keep the css-fill to stay on the inside of the pot. How can I fill the inside of the pot but also make sure that the "fill" stays inside the pot image on different screen sizes?

Here is the html/css that I have so far:

```
  <div id="main">
    <div class="image1 five columns offset-by-two">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DbBqGTp.png">
    </div>
  </div>

#main{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#main img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 57%;
    left: 47%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 470px;
    height: 470px;
    border-radius:250px;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:500px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vjpprtfu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool idea! Make a mask div with the coffee liquid inside of it. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fuk291kf/

The markup loops like this:

```
  <div id="main">
      <div class="circle-mask">
         <div class="liquid"></div>
      </div>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DbBqGTp.png">
  </div>
```

and the css:

```
.circle-mask {
    position: absolute;
    width: 77%;
    height: 77%;
    top:45px;
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:block;
}

.liquid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000;
}
```

To change the level of the liquid, raise or lower the top value of `.liquid`

Now you'll have to add another div that is positioned absolute to the circle which clips the coffee coming out of the bottom of the pot.

Comment: Definitely thankful for the time you put into your response, however this makes it really difficult(for me, at least) to find a way to keep the pot centered in the middle and have it scale down when the page gets smaller(mobile in mind). Here is a fiddle with scaling and alignment: https://jsfiddle.net/fuk291kf/3/
I'm working on an AI project that uses computer vision to detect a real coffee pot and how filled it is. I am trying to make a webpage to complement this that can display what the computer vision is seeing in a "pretty" way. How would I mimic the liquid level but keeping the scaling?

Comment: Have you tried using `<svg>`? [Here's a tutorial on animating `<svg>` elements](https://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/).